# url design for RESTful services

Tags: java, rest

I have a resource called `Pricing` which i want to retrieve. An `Offer` can have pricing and a `Promo` can have `Pricing` resource and there is another entity `Customer` with which `Pricing` can be mapped. I want to retrieve `Pricing` based on either one of `OfferId`/`PromoId`/`CustomerId`.

To design the URLs for this, i'm running into two options:

**Option 1:** Pass it as query string

```
/pricing?OfferId=234&PromoId=345&CustomerId=543234
```

**Option 2:** Have three APIs

```
/pricing/offer?id=234
/pricing/promo?id=345
/pricing/customer?id=543234
```

IMO, `OfferId`/`PromoId`/`CustomerId` should be treated as attribute of the resource. Therefore pass attribute as query string.I'm more inclined towards Option 1.

Option 2 avoids if else condition to retrieve the resource and looks much cleaner but does it seems to be supporting REST standard of URL design?

What's the REST standard to design the URL. Which option would you recommend?

Comment: I think the general consensus is that you should have 3 urls going like /pricing/offer/1234. See example http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Build-truly-RESTful-API-194a6253

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that would be most clean and follows standard pathing would be:

```
/pricing/offer/234
/pricing/promo/345
/pricing/customer/543234
```

With the layout being: `/pricing/${offer|promo|customer|/${PathParamForId}`

Which you could then do as three separate methods one each for offer/promo/customer.

Then you just have to make sure your API is well documented so users know the expected behaviors for the paths. (Difference between offer vs promo lookup and etc.)

Comment: However, from the URL itself, it seems suggesting we are retrieving an offer/promo/customer, instead of pricing

Comment: Unless you view it as "we are retrieving pricing for the category of offer/promo/customer with the ID of X". There would need to be more details about how the objects are laid out/stored and business logic to know the optimal structure and what's necessary. Either way it shouldn't be using Query Params but rather Path Params.

Comment: I also have same opinion as @AdrianShum. In case of option 1, it's self explanatory that it retrieves pricing resource based on certain criteria where as in case of option 2, we will have to let reader know to read it in certain context as suggested by you. Why are you not in favor of using query params ?

Answer (score 5):

I prefer the Option 1.
The Option 2 has the following defects:

1. it may confuse users. for instance, `/pricing/offer/234` seems to
   represent an `Offer` resource, not a `Pricing` resource.
2. in business logic, an `Offer` resource contains a `Pricing`, but
   `/pricing/offer/234` represent right on the contrary way. It seems
   like a `Pricing` resource contains an `Offer` resource.

Actually, the Option 1, has some problems too. for example,

```
/pricing?OfferId=234&PromoId=345&CustomerId=543234
```

will get three Pricings, right? It seems

```
/pricings?OfferId=234&PromoId=345&CustomerId=543234
```

is more reasonable.

Another option you can think about is Option 3:

```
/offer/234/pricing
/promo/345/pricing
/cusomer/543234/pricing
```

hope it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is already suggested by [@Freedom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266556/freedom) but I think it deserves its own answer and reasoning.

You want to retrieve a pricing - but that doesn't mean you have to start the URL with it `pricing`.

`Promo`,`Offer` and `Customer` look like resources. They probably have have their own URLs, like `offer/123`. Even if they don't have URLs they still seem to be a logical container/composition element of a `Pricing`. So a `Pricing` should be a sub-resource of those.

```
/offers/234/pricing
/promos/345/pricing
/customers/543234/pricing
```

If a pricing has its own id too, you can still add an additional way to list all pricings or get them by that ID:

```
/pricings
/pricings/12
```